# No file access for txt file in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, file, text, io

I tried to save a text file to internal storage of the app but it does not work

Code is

```
 val defFileName = "text.def"
    val ioFile = File(defFileName)
ioFile.createnewFile()
        ioFile.writeText("Hello World")
```

I have tried different code versions to achive it but every time I got

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
                        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: hello_file: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

EROFS ReadOnlyFileSystem

Any help?

Edit:

I get the path with

```
mContext.applicationInfo.dataDir.toString()
```

This code runs without error and ioDefFile ="xxx.def"

```
  val fileOutputStream:FileOutputStream

  try {

            fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(ioDefFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
         fileOutputStream.write("just a textString".toByteArray())

        }catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

This code says -> open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

```
 try{
        val fileWriter = FileWriter(ioDefFile)

        for (x in 0..(DSSize-1)){
            fileWriter.write(dl[x]+ "\n")
           
        }

        fileWriter.close()
    } catch (exception: Exception){
        println(exception.message)
    }
```

Did not see the error in Code 2 - it did not work with oder without adding the path

Comment: `"text.def"` is not a valid filesystem path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works :)

```
val foStream: FileOutputStream  

try {

            foStream = context.openFileOutput(ioDefFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

            for (x in 0..(DSSize - 1)) {
                foStream.bufferedWriter().write(dl[x])
                foStream.bufferedWriter().newLine()
                
            }


        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

from the code provided you are trying to create a file and write to it.
as mentioned the comment the variable `defFileName` wont provide valid path

so you need to modify your code into something like this for result

```
    val defFileName = "text.def"
    val ioFile = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),
        "name.txt")
    ioFile.writeText("hello")
```